# Delete all products of a particular category & all it's subcategories through single MySQL Query in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Can somebody suggest me a query to delete all products of only a particular category & it's subcategories in Magento ?

I have tried creating one but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this in one query because you need modify more than one table.

I think you can use transaction for your task.